# OpenLayers. Would like one CSS for placement of custom control for mobile and desktop browsers

Tags: css, openlayers

I have a custom control on an OpenLayer map.

I'm using `normalize.css` (and tried removing it which made no difference) and this:

```
.help {
    top: 5rem;
    left: .5em;
}
```

On desktop Chrome & Safari browsers, the "?" button is displayed thus:

[image]

but on mobile Chrome & Safari browsers, the "?" button is displayed higher on the screen:

[image]

I can't remove the use of OpenLayers and still have a relevant example.
Any ideas/suggestions as to why I'm getting this difference across browsers?

Comment: OpenLayers uses a larger font size for controls on touch devices, so controls which are placed below others need to be moved if on a touch device - see the OpenLayers css for ZoonSlider https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/ol.css#L292-L305

Comment: that makes sense, @Mike. why doesn't my use of `top: 5rem;` take font-size into account and move my control further on devices using a larger font?

Comment: You are positioning the control on the map viewport, the font size change is applied to controls, not the map itself.